# Quarkus use Client Roles instead of Realm Roles

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, quarkus

In my application, I would like to use client roles instead of realm roles.

I did this specification in Spring-Boot application, however, I cannot make it right in Quarkus application.

In my application, I would like to use client roles instead of realm roles.

I did this specification in Spring-Boot application, however, I cannot make it right in Quarkus application. I have a client, let's call it "test-client". And that "test-client" has a role of "test-role1". The configuration in Spring-Boot will be:

```
keycloak:
  realm: myrealm
  resource: test-client
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080
  use-resource-role-mappings: true # this setting determines whether the roles are mapped from realm level or client level
  bearer-only: true
```

```java
    @Path("/my-path")
    @RolesAllowed("test-role1")
    public String testPath() {
        return "success";
    }
```

And everything works fine. However, in quarkus side, there is no `use-resource-role-mappings` property. How can I achieve that?

application.properties in Quarkus:

```
quarkus.oidc.client-id=test-client
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=test-client-secret
# There is no use-resource-role-mappings
```

If I try to create a **realm** role named "test-role1", and assign that role to the requestor (whoever is calling this endpoint), then everything works fine. But I have to use client roles, not realm roles.

a part of jwt token is like this:

```
"realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization",
      "default-roles-myrealm"
    ]
  },
"resource_access": {
    "test-client": {
      "roles": [
        "test-role1"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out a solution.

In application properties, one can define the role-claim-path, which (as far as I understand) results in, Java will look into that path of the token in order to compare whether the role exists there.

```
quarkus.oidc.roles.role-claim-path=resource_access/test-client/roles
```